How do I create an integration test in Spring Boot for a job application?
I will provide an example application to illustrate what I need. I have a job application that is scheduled to run daily in Kubernetes. This application serves as the entry point for the job.
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
class JobGenerateProductApplication(private val jobStarter: JobStarter) : CommandLineRunner {
    override fun run(vararg args: String?) {
        jobStarter.startJob()
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<JobGenerateProductApplication>(*args)
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
}

So, I have this class, JobStarter, which performs some operations. It makes a request to an external service and saves the data to a database. Here is a simplified example:
@Service
class JobStarter(
    private val productRepository: ProductRepository,
    private val balanceService: BalanceService
    ) {

    fun startJob() {
        val balance = balanceService.getBalance()
        val product = Product(name = balance.name, balance = balance.balance)
    }
}

So here is where the problems start: I am trying to create an integration test for this job using H2 and mocking the external service, but I am struggling with it. I want to have some test scenarios, like 'the request failed' or 'success'. The problem is that if I use only @SpringBootTest, it automatically starts the job without passing through my @Test methods. If I use @ContextConfiguration, I have to manually load all the H2 and transaction manager configurations, because if I don't, I get the error 'ProductRepository bean not found'.
So, what do I need? I need to be able to test the JobStarter without having to configure all the database stuff manually. I want to use what is defined in application.properties. I have tried many different approaches, like setting the properties with the @TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties") annotation, but nothing seems to work.
My application.properties from tests:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:user_db;MODE=Oracle;DEFAULT_NULL_ORDERING=HIGH;
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.sql.init.platform=h2
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2

In this scenario, It will never reach my @Test:
@SpringBootTest
class JobStarterTest {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var jobStarter: JobStarter

    @Test
    fun `successful`() {
    }
}

In this I have to create beans of dataSource, entityManagerFactory and transactionManager, besides of not having logs and other configured stuff from application.properties:
@SpringBootTest
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ContextConfiguration(
    classes = [JobStarter::class, ProductRepository::class]
)
class JobStarterTest {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var jobStarter: JobStarter

    @MockBean
    private lateinit var balanceService: BalanceService
    
    @Test
    fun `successful`() {
    }
}


What about ?
@SpringBootTest(classes= JobGenerateProductApplication::class)

See here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-testing-separate-data-source

Actually, the whole problem was because of CommandLineRunner. It was starting the context. I followed this page and it worked: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-junit-prevent-runner-beans-testing-execution
